# ViewPager with ImageViews having pinch-zoom and gestures capabilities - view reuse issue

Tags: java, android, touch, gesture

I have a ViewPager with custom ImageView-based class as ViewPager childrens. In my ImageView I have implemnted gesture handling - pinch and 2-finger zoom and image move. Now my problem is that ViewPager reuses view and there is no mechanism for saving particular view state of child views. In my case it results in following - user zooms and/or moves image on particular ImageView, then ViewAdapter reuses view for current view and the image gets display with default scale/position. I wonder how to save the view state so that after view reuse I can load the last state of view to have the correct zoom/move state. 
Does anybody have some hints?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use setTag and save the state of the modified child view. If getTag is not null, you can restore the state of the child.

Comment: The problem is that views get recycled so the Tah of one's View is then the Tag of another.